# How to retrieve record from data extension of different business unit

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

I am using this call in AMPScript

```
https://www.exacttargetapis.com/data/v1/customobjectdata/key/[Data extension key]?$filter= Name%20eq%20'Test'
```

It's working in POSTMAN

Comment: You want to call the REST API in AMPscript?

Comment: yes right.i am just using same call in AMPscript.

Comment: What's the context?  An email, CloudPage?